# HTML5 video.currentTime returning NaN only for some users

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have a fairly simple bit of JS that uses AJAX to keep track of a user's progress in a video. This is working beautifully for dozens upon dozens of users but there are a handful who are occasionally not tracking at all.

I discovered after much investigating that this is because for some reason `cur_time = Math.round(cvid.currrentTime);` is returning `NaN`.  When this happens it happens for every single interval of the function. I have been unable to recreate the error myself in any browser or on any device I have so I can't check console.

Does anyone know of any reasons why `cvid.currentTime` wouldn't return a valid number even though the video is clearly properly loaded in order to call `cvid.oncanplay`?

```js
var interv;

var cvid = document.getElementById("cvideo");
cvid.oncanplay = function() {
  interval_track();
};

function ajaxtrack(ended) {
  var cur_time = Math.round(cvid.currrentTime);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/ce/inc/ajax.php?action=vid_track",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: {
      course_id: '<?=$course_id?>',
      user_id: '<?=$user_id?>',
      cur_time: cur_time,
      ended: ended,
    },
  });
}

function interval_track() {
  clearInterval(interv);
  interv = setInterval(function() {
    if (!cvid.paused) {
      ajaxtrack();
    }
  }, 15000);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, however I'd suggest removing the `async: false` in the AJAX request as it's incredibly bad practice, and you don't need it here. In fact, it's possible it's the cause of the issue. I'd also suggest making sure that the DOM has loaded before you execute this code. You may be encountering a race condition.

Comment: Do you know in what browsers that occurs? `Math.round(undefined)` is `NaN`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Thanks I'll try that, I may have already though I can't recall.

Comment: @str It's hard to find any rhyme or reason as far as browsers and devices go.  Some of the users having problems have been on iOS, Android, PC, Mac, Chrome, Firefox, Edge & IE (ew)   and far more users are also on all of those devices and browsers with 100% functionality.